# xsl:fo doesn't create a multipage PDF inspite of page-break

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo

Below code tried to call templates, the body is a repeating table can span multiple pages.
If I try to render the PDF from this, it is giving only a single page which is overflowing and does not go into the next page. Any Ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <!-- ================================= OVERALL LAYOUT======================= -->
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <!-- ========= LAYOUT ========= -->
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="any-page" page-width="210mm" page-height="296mm" margin-left="0mm" margin-top="0mm">
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom="2.1cm" margin-top="5.40cm" margin-left="0cm" margin-right="0cm" padding="0cm"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="header" extent="85mm"/>
                <fo:region-after region-name="footer" extent="81mm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <!-- ========= OVERALL LAYOUT ========= -->
            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="A4">
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="any-page" page-position="any"/>
                </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            </fo:page-sequence-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <!-- =================================CONTENT TEMPLATE CALL================================= -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//XY">
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
                <!-- ========= HEADER ========= -->
                <fo:static-content flow-name="header">
                    <fo:block break-before="page"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="XY = 'XY ">
                            <xsl:call-template name="XY_HEADER"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:call-template name="YY_HEADER"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </fo:static-content>
                <!-- ========= FOOTER ========= -->
                <fo:static-content flow-name="footer">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="XY = 'XY' ">
                            <xsl:call-template name="XY_FOOTER"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:call-template name="YY_FOOTER"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </fo:static-content>
                <!-- ========= BODY ========= -->
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="XY = 'XY' ">
                            <xsl:call-template name="XY_BOD"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:call-template name="YY_BOD"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                        <fo:block id="last-page"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="XY_BODY" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:block-container position="absolute" left="5mm" top="95mm" height="200mm" width="200mm">
        <fo:block text-align="left" font-size="3mm" page-break-before="always">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" height="10.4cm" width="27cm" top="0.7cm" left="0cm" padding="0mm" position="absolute" font-size="10">
                <fo:table-body>
                ..
                ...
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
    <fo:block-container position="absolute" left="5mm" top="286mm" height="5mm" width="200mm">
        <fo:block padding-left="1mm" text-align="right">
            <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="last-page"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Page break in FO is auto process or you may use page-break itself. It seems to me your table has dozen number or columns which are unable to fit in your provided paper size format. You may reduce column length, wrapping text or can change your paper size to get desired output.

Comment: Changing the length doesnt help, it needs to flow into the next page automatically, but it doesnt. Thats what has stumped me.

Comment: Please change your page-sequence which you are generating withing <xsl:for-each select="//XY"> element. It doesn't necessary. FO would take care of it automatically. Use your for each in body flow only. Have a look http://www.learn-xsl-fo-tutorial.com/Page-Layout.cfm#h1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using an absolutely-positioned block container:  it encapsulates your table on a single page and so your table isn't breaking to a new page.  If you didn't use an absolutely-positioned block container then your table would be free to engage page-breaking and regular page flow.